# Press a button widget and Fragment problem

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build a simple Google Map app on Android Studio. The app has one button and when user clicks on it, the google map fragment or page must open. I spend countless hours but the map doesn't open even though the code compiles. I'm using Nexus 5X emulator.

//MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DialogTitle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private static final int ERROR_DIALOGUE_REQUEST = 9001;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

    if(isservicesOK()){
        init();
    }
        }
    });
}

//one button to navigate to the map
private void init(){
      Button btnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMap);
      btnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          @Override
                  public void onClick(View view){
              //Log.i("App","mine");
              //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"its working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
              startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}
//if the map doesn't work, these are the following commands:
public boolean isservicesOK(){
    Log.d(TAG, "isservicesOK: checking google services ");

    int available = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(MainActivity.this);

    if(available == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        Log.d(TAG, "isservicesOK: Google play service is working ");
        return true;
    } //everything is fine the user can make map requests
    else if(GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(available)){
        //error occur but we can resolve it. if they have the wrong OS
        Log.d(TAG, "isservicesOK: error but we can fix it ");
        Dialog dialog = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(MainActivity.this, available, ERROR_DIALOGUE_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    }else{//you cant do anything now buddy!
        Toast.makeText(this, "you cant make map requests", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
 }
```

//MapActivity.java

```
  package com.example.myapplication;

  import android.Manifest;
  import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
  import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
  import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
  import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.Toast;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
  import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
  import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
  import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

  public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
  OnMapReadyCallback{

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
    Toast.makeText(this, "map is ready" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready Beta");
    mMap = googleMap;
}

private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

//VARIABLES
private Boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
private GoogleMap mMap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
     //check for location permission
    getLocationPermission();
}

private void initMap()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initialsing map");
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
}
private void getLocationPermission(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permission");
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                COURSE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;

        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults){
    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called yaar");
    mLocationPermissionGranted = false;

    switch(requestCode){
        case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
            if(grantResults.length > 0){
                for(int j = 0; j < grantResults.length; j++){
                    if(grantResults[j] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                //initialize the map
                initMap();
            }
        }
    }
}

 }
```

//build.gradle: app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
 }

 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
//google play services
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
 }
```

//Logcat:

```
2019-03-21 10:44:51.332 25541-25541/com.example.myapplication 
I/e.myapplicatio: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-03-21 10:44:51.603 25541-25541/com.example.myapplication 
W/e.myapplicatio: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-03-21 10:44:51.759 25541-25541/com.example.myapplication 
I/e.myapplicatio: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-03-21 10:44:52.252 25541-25541/com.example.myapplication 
W/e.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;- 
>computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z 
(light greylist, reflection)
2019-03-21 10:44:52.252 25541-25541/com.example.myapplication 
W/e.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;- 
>makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-03-21 10:44:52.560 25541-25541/com.example.myapplication 
D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
 2019-03-21 10:44:52.652 25541-25566/com.example.myapplication 
 I/ConfigStore: 
 android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay 
  retrieved: 0
  2019-03-21 10:44:52.652 25541-25566/com.example.myapplication 
  I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
  2019-03-21 10:44:52.652 25541-25566/com.example.myapplication 
  D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
 2019-03-21 10:44:52.652 25541-25566/com.example.myapplication 
  W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with 
 EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, 
   retrying without...
  2019-03-21 10:44:52.652 25541-25566/com.example.myapplication 
   D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
  2019-03-21 10:44:52.670 25541-25566/com.example.myapplication 
   D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xea564e80: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
  2019-03-21 10:44:52.688 25541-25566/com.example.myapplication 
  D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea564e80: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xea4ce580)
   2019-03-21 10:44:52.865 25541-25566/com.example.myapplication 
  D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea564e80: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xea4ce580)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here I have implemented as

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And coded in Activity like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

**P.S I dont use button directly load Map Fragment in Activity**